# How do I import a CSV to MySQL where there is a space in a column name?

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import

I have been handed a very large CSV file that needs to be imported to a database.

I have done this before and know the general syntax, however, I am failing and getting errors on the column names as they contain a space.

I have tried different sorts of quotes without luck and have been searching the internet for the past hour.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backticks: `, to the left of the 1 key.